# Memory assignments optimizations

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, optimization, memory-barriers

It is well known fact that compilers can mix assignments order in order to optimize execution,
so-

```
a=b;
c=d;
```

Can be actually performed

```
c=d;
a=b;
```

However with the following code:

```
a=b;
x=a;
func(x);
```

By the time `func(x)` is called, `x` must contain `b` first, or else result can be unpredictable.

Now, what about the following code:

```
int *addr1 = some_addr;
int *addr2 = (int *)0xf00;

/* The following applies:
 *      some_other_addr >= some_addr
 */
for (addr1; addr1 < some_other_addr; addr1++) 
{
    *addr1 += 1;
}

*addr2 *= 8;
```

When `addr2` points to an address in the range of the `for` loop, we need to know whether or not it is promised that `*addr2` will be incremented before the multiplition in 8, as if not, and some optimization step placed `*addr2 *= 8;` before the `for` loop, the result of `*addr2` will be different than if it would have been executed without an optimization.

Would the answer be different in case `some_addr` and `some_other_addr` are defined in the scope and in case they are passed as arguments? because at the first case it is quite easy for the compiler to know that `*addr2` is inside the range of the `for` loop, while at the second case it's not that obvious.

And also, if we look at it from the Assembly perspective, let's take for example a sample `reset_handler` code snippet of `bss` section initialization:

```
    ldr  r1, =__BSS_SIZE__
    cmp  r1, #0
    beq  FINISHED_LABEL
    ldr  r0, =__BSS_START__
    ldr  r2, =0
LOOP_LABEL:
    str  r2, [r0]
    add  r0, r4
    subs r1, r4
    bne  LOOP_LABEL
```

If the next instruction after this code (at `FINISHED_LABEL`) loads a value (`ldr`) from address in the bss range, is it promised that the content will be valid (0) at that time?

Comment: Comparing two pointers using the `<` operator gives undefined behaviour in C unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object (or one past the end). When behaviour is undefined, the C standards permit an implementation (e.g. a compiler or the optimiser) do do what it likes, whether that makes sense to the programmer or not. If you want guarantees (or at least a justification for complaining to the compiler vendor if it gets something wrong, or reliably passing your tests cases) you need to avoid undefined behaviour. Your example, from the information you have given. does not.

Comment: You can try it out if there is a compiler which mixes statements, but I think there should not be any: https://godbolt.org/g/mPhoos

Comment: if no compiler mixes `for` statements and assignment, I can slightly change my original question and ask the following: if `addr1` and `addr2` are pointers pointing to the same address, but `addr2` is initialized hard coded with the address, while `addr1` is initialized with the address passed as an argument, and instead of the `for` loop there is only `*addr1 += 1`, what is promised regarding the content of the address? if `*addr1 += 1` and `*addr2 *= 8` can be mixed, result will be unpredictable. Anyway, the question regarding the Assembly part remains the same.

Comment: In the code `a=b; x=a; func(x);` there is no `x=b;` . So I do not understand your comment "x=b must happen first"

Comment: @bolov - that's exactly my question. will the memory content be increment before or not, as the same memory address is referenced from two different variables.

Comment: This seems like a really long-winded way of asking "does the compiler have to consider that function parameters might alias" to which the answer is Yes if they're both the same type and not `restrict`

Comment: "`int *addr2 = 0xf00`" which compiler accepts that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the compiler has to do to get this right is called ["alias analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_analysis).

If the compiler can prove that `addr2` isn't in the range that `addr1` loops over, it can reorder it or keep `*addr2` in a register throughout the loop.

This is a very useful optimization for a case like `for(...; addr1++) { *addr1 += *addr2; }` to avoid reloading `addr2` every time, and one of the reasons [the `restrict` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) exists.

**If inputs might overlap, compilers can (and *do*) emit code that *checks* for overlap** and runs an optimized (e.g. auto-vectorized) loop if there's no overlap, or runs a safe loop if there is overlap.

---

If a compiler *can't* prove that a transformation will give the same final results as the C abstract machine, it can't do the transformation.  (I say "final" because the order of stores to memory aren't part of the observable results, unless you use `std::atomic`.  So compile-time transformations aren't allowed to break *single-threaded* code, very similar to what out-of-order CPUs do: provide the illusion of everything happening in program order *for a single thread*.)

**The as-if rule only allows optimizations that work in *all* cases that don't lead to UB**, including obscure stuff like `unsigned size = 0xffffffff`, which can often lead to compilers not being allowed to do optimizations you hoped for, unless you tweak your source.

UB is key for allowing some optimizations (like not redoing sign-extension of a signed array index inside a loop).  See 
[What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: does your answer applies also to the assembly part of my question? are optimizations performed after code transformed into assembly?

Comment: @user2162550: Assemblers don't reorder instructions.  There are some binary-to-binary optimizers that try to find *safe* optimizations that don't change the behaviour of a program, where the input is an already-compiled executable.  But those are rare, and would be buggy if they moved a load before a store to the same location.  Similarly, as I said in the first paragraph of the 2nd section of this answer, **the cardinal rule of out-of-order execution is to preserve the *illusion* that the machine instructions run in program order**.  So yes later loads from the BSS would get zero.

Comment: so optimizations only happens before the code is translated to assembly? assembly code will never get optimized (as a general, not the binary-to-binary rar cases)? I'm talking about build/compile time not run-time CPU optimizations.

Comment: @user2162550: Right, compilation from C to asm is where optimizing compilers do the heavy lifting to figure out how to emit efficient asm instructions, because that's what will run on the hardware.  (And many compilers emit machine code directly, rather than piping asm text into an assembler the way gcc does).  Much of the optimization happens on an internal representation of the program logic, but some of it happens *while* translating that to asm (e.g. peephole optimizations like replacing `mov rax, 0` with `xor eax,eax` if flags can be clobbered at that point).

Comment: @user2162550: The only optimization that happens on asm / machine code is pipelined out-of-order execution by the CPU hardware.  See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/350024#350024 for some details about how CPUs find an exploit instruction-level parallelism.

Comment: do you have any documentation regarding the compilation optimization which do not take place in the assembler?

Comment: @user2162550: see some of the links in the answer I linked in my last comment.  http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~lenharth/cs378/fall14/8%20-%20LoopOptimizations.pdf has some neat stuff.  See **Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk: [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)** for more info on seeing how compilers optimize.  (You can use the compiler explorer site for ARM instead of x86, using the same examples Matt looks at for x86.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - the loop optimization link is dead, but archived:  https://web.archive.org/web/20170517030057/http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~lenharth/cs378/fall14/8%20-%20LoopOptimizations.pdf

Comment: It might be worth noting that even if the compiler cannot statically prove non-aliasing at compile time, it could still insert a runtime check before the loop to see if the ranges overlap, and use the non-aliasing fast version of the loop if they don't. This idea is used in practice today by some compilers.